# What is name of this object, how can i use it?

Tags: iphone, uiview

In some video i see this screen shot.
What is name of this object?

http://www.valar.ru/gallery/1110/screen_shot_20101109_at_102020_pm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a standard UI component. But you can easily replicate it using 1 UIView as a background and container for a number of UIButtons + some controller code to ensure that only one button is selected at a time (if I understand correctly how it is supposed to work).

Probably you can find a 3rd party library that already implements this kind of control - have a look at TTTabGrid class in three20 library (although it is not exactly the same as you have on your screenshot)